# Ubuntu 16.04.3 - Nvidia driver causing error (login loop) + GPU not showing in Xsettings

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, login

After installing Ubuntu the system would hang after the bios boot logo, which I fixed using the following solution:

Hold shift after bios logo to enter GRUB, go to advanced options, press E on top selection and add:

```
nomodeset
```

I made this change permenant by entering the desktop and entering in terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add nomodeset to the linux line and then running the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Once that was sorted have tried installing several Nvidia drivers including ver 375 recommended via the additional drivers section, all cause a login loop to occur.

To fix the issue and enter the desktop again I must use the following command to switch to IGP:

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

I am guessing this has something to do with the kernel 4.10 which I am using.

When I enter Xsettings with Nvidia drivers installed it shows no GPU. 
Here are my specs:

Intel I7 7700HQ
16GB ram
GTX 1050
Intel HD 630 graphics

Does anyone know any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing weird problems recently with a XPS 15 laptop. It worked fine and suddently it went to hell. Tried reinstalling in every way, had crashes, loops, ...

What has worked for me is reinstalling Ubuntu without asking for updates or proprietary drivers during the install. Then, connect to a network and update your package repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I went to System Setting -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers and changed the drivers for Intel and nvidia to proprietary, then rebooted. Seems to work now. I wouldn't try to update to latest released 384.90 and stick with the 375 ones for now. Also I'm avoiding upgrading the system for now as my system was highly unstable when I asked the Ubuntu install process to download the latest updates (Ubuntu 16.04.3 + 4.10.0-35 kernel)

Comment: Using the "Additional Drivers" menu instead of manually installing the driver is not the same as the Ubuntu menu will do some behind the scenes magic to blacklist nouveau driver and stuff like that. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thats interesting I have tried Linux Mint which uses kernel 4.8 and I have had no issues but I would prefer to use Ubuntu instead. I will try and install Ubuntu without installing updates and see if that works.